# Replacing words in string with cycle for

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, replace

```
import re
frase = "I read some text writed here"
ea = ["ReplaceA", "ReplaceB", "ReplaceC"]
eax = ["some", "writed", "here"]
for e in ea:
            print(e)
            count = ea.count(e)
            print(count)
            ready_message = frase.replace(eax[count], for e in ax)  
print(ready_message)
```

Result: ReplaceA
1
ReplaceB
1
ReplaceC
1
I read some text ReplaceB here

I want that ready_message is:

I read ReplaceA text ReplaceB ReplaceC

and not:

I read some text ReplaceB here

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.zip`

```
frase = "I read some text writed here"
ea = ["ReplaceA", "ReplaceB", "ReplaceC"]
eax = ["some", "writed", "here"]
for i,j in zip(ea,eax):
    frase=frase.replace(j,i)
print(frase)
```